# exceptions.TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python

I called this:

```
for count in result:
    print "Exist: %s" % count
    self.IdCode = count

self.IdCode += 1
```

and received this error:

```
exceptions.TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Why don't you just do `self.IdCode = result[-1] + 1`? What is the purpose of the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

`self.IdCode` is a tuple of values (e.g. `(1, 2)`), and you cannot add a integer to a tuple (an explanation of why is easily found if you Google your error message).

From your code, it seems that `self.IdCode += 1` is to be incrementing an integer. However, each `count` in result (or at least the last `count`) is a tuple, not an integer. `self.IdCode` is being assigned to such a tuple, then you try to add an integer, which you cannot do.

Comment: more what I want to do is a simple sum

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to version difference! I can concatenate two tuples by creating a 3rd tuple in IPython notebook and v3.4. However, I get the same error in v2.7.

Not sure why does this happen.

from IPython:

```
t1 = (1,2)    
t1    
(1, 2)    
t2 = (2,3)
t3 = t1 + t2
t3
(1, 2, 2, 3)
```

*Learning Python! :)